# Kerberos ticket is sent only when compatibilty mode in IE is turned on

Tags: internet-explorer, kerberos, kdc

On our Kerberos setup, when our application URL is accessed using IE 11, the Kerberos ticket is not sent along with the request.
However, when the compatibility mode (display intranet sites in compatibility view) is turned on, then the Kerberos ticket is sent and authentication works fine. We are using IE 11.
When using developer tool, the user agent string is changed from Default to Internet Explorer 10, then also it works.

The authentication always works fine on chrome.

UPDATE:
We observed the traffic on wireshark, found out that when compatibility mode is OFF, then server is not challenging the client for negotiation.
However, when compatibility is ON, server challenges the client by sending 401 response.

Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi.  How do you know Kerberos ticket is not sent to the web server when in IE compatibility mode?  On the client, have you verified using network monitoring tool or using the command _klist tickets_?

Comment: Yes. I've verified this by debugging the server side. When the compatibility mode is on, only in that case the ticket is received on server end.

Comment: Also verified using klists and kinit commands.

Comment: I see. What I was driving at though, was whether the Kerberos ticket shows up on the _client-side_ Kerberos cache, when IE compatibility is turned _off_.   On the client, please clear the IE browser cache, close IE, run _klist purge_, then hit the URL again with IE compatibility turned _off_.  Then, run _klist tickets_ on the client machine again and let us know if you see the ticket.

Comment: Performed following, all on client machine.
c:\windows\system32> kinit <principle name>
_Password for <principle name>@<domain>
New ticket is stored in cache file_

Compatibility is off. Cleared browser cache. closed the browser.
Executed klist purge. Received following output.
_Current LogonId is 0:0x66190
        Deleting all tickets:
        Ticket(s) purged!_
Starter the browser and hit the URL. Ticket is not received on server side.
Exceuted _klists tickets_ but shows following output.
_Current LogonId is 0:0x66190
Cached Tickets: (0)_

Comment: Ok, we'll come back to this. With IE compatibility mode on the client turned off, does the user gets challenged with an authentication dialog box?  And if so, when they manually enter their credentials, do they get logged in with those?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131611/discussion-between-t-heron-and-bhushan-karmarkar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we have identified the exact root cause and the solution for this issue.

**Root Cause:**
We are using the cas 3.5.3 implementation for Kerberos. This library maintains a list of User Agents; to be precise substring of User-Agent string.
This list is used to check whether the browser is compatible for Kerberos authentication or not.

There are changes in User Agent String of IE 11. Refer this [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869301(v=vs.85).aspx)

The user agent string sent by IE 11 (In non-compatibility mode) was not supported by the CAS 3.5.3 implementation which we are using.

The difference between the User Agent Strings from two requests (IE 11 compatibility mode ON and OFF) is as follows:
With compatibility ON
***Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/8.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)***

With compatibility OFF
***Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko***

First user agent is processed by the library (it searches for the word ‘MSIE’ which is in the list of supported User Agents), while other is discarded as it doesn’t contain the word ‘MSIE’.
The problem did not occur with IE 9/10 because their corresponding user agents contain the string ‘MSIE’.

**Solution:**
The list of user agents maintained by the cas3.5.3 is overridden and the entry corresponding to the user agent of IE11 is added to it.
Now the request gets processed property and the Kerberos login Is working properly.

I hope this will be helpful for other developers working on *cas* library.